# Can't connect to Firebird (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, firebird, jaybird

I'm new to Ubuntu and I just installed it on a computer. I installed Samba and shared the folders "/samba" and "/hd". I downloaded and installed Firebird and copied my database that I created on Windows and put it in "/samba". This is my Java code:

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/samba/LNX.FDB", "sysdba",
                "masterkey");
        return connection;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        getConnection();
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544344. I/O error during "open" operation for file "samba/LNX.FDB"
Error while trying to open file
null
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource.getConnection(FBDataSource.java:120)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractDriver.connect(AbstractDriver.java:136)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at br.com.ipsnet.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:16)
    at br.com.ipsnet.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.main(ConnectionFactory.java:22)
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.gds.GDSException: I/O error during "open" operation for file "samba/LNX.FDB"
Error while trying to open file
null
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.readStatusVector(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2098)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.receiveResponse(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2048)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.internalAttachDatabase(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:463)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.iscAttachDatabase(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:411)
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnection.<init>(FBManagedConnection.java:105)
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(FBManagedConnectionFactory.java:509)
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBStandAloneConnectionManager.allocateConnection(FBStandAloneConnectionManager.java:65)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource.getConnection(FBDataSource.java:118)
    ... 5 more
```

If I go to "/samba" and type:

```
isql-fb
connect "localhost:/samba/LNX.FDB" user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';
```

It works perfectly fine, I can select, delete, update, insert,... with no problem at all.

If I use IBExpert on my Windows machine to connect to my database in Ubuntu it says:

```
Unable to complete network request to host "Server-Test".
Failed to estabilish connection.
```

If I use Flamerobin it says:

```
An assertion failed!

../src/common/strconv.cpp(3031): assert "Assert failure" failed in wxCSConv(): invalid encoding value in wxCSConv ctor
```

But it connects. I can select, delete, update,...

Comment: Maybe  You will need to allow access to the directory for IBExpert, your Java App ...

Comment: I did "chmod 755 /samba -R" and the error is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the path you specified in the connection string `jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/samba/LNX.FDB` is `samba/LNX.FDB`, and not `/samba/LNX.FDB`. Relative paths depend on the platform, user and Firebird configuration.

As documented in the [Jaybird release notes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.10/release_notes.html#pure-java) you need to use `jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050//samba/LNX.FDB`:

> On Linux the root `/` should be included in the path. A database located on `/opt/firebird/db.fdb` should use the URL below (note the double slash after port!).
>
> ```
> jdbc:firebirdsql://host:port//opt/firebird/db.fdb
> ```

Alternatively, you could define an alias instead and use that.

As to your problems with IB Expert and Flamerobin, they seem to be unrelated and should really be separate questions. The IB Expert problem seems to be that you specified a hostname (`Server-Test`) that cannot be resolved to an (IPv4) IP address or the server does not accept the connect request. A reason could be that the Firebird service is not listening on that IP address; on Ubuntu by default Firebird only listens on localhost. The flamerobin error sounds like a bug in Flamerobin (or you are specifying an unsupported connection character set(?)).

About your use of samba and using a network share: do not put Firebird databases on a network share. Accessing a Firebird database on a network share (especially from multiple servers), could corrupt the database. If you want to access a Firebird database from multiple hosts, then you need to use a Firebird server and connect through that.

Comment: This worked. Thank you! Now I'll be able to focus on fixing my IBExpert issue.

Answer (score 0):

About IBExpert : This screenshot is example how to look registration form to connect with ubuntu:

[image]